# Failing to get process output c#

Tags: c#

I am meeting a unexplained behavior when trying to read a newly spawned process output -

This is the code i am using:

```
    p.StartInfo.Arguments += "-o Kd.pddl -f Kp.pddl";        
    StreamWriter planeWriter = new StreamWriter(m_planStream);
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);
    p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => planeWriter.WriteLine(args.Data);
    p.Start();

    p.BeginOutputReadLine();
    p.WaitForExit();
    m_planStream.Position = 0;
    StreamReader planReader = new StreamReader(m_planStream);
    m_sFFOutput = planReader.ReadToEnd();
    List<string> lPlan = new List<string>();
    Console.WriteLine(m_sFFOutput);
```

It is quite straightforward, and for most outputs it works, which is why i say this is unexplained.

I am loading  the program each time with different input (Kd.pddl and Kp.pddl).
for some inputs its all work fine, but for some inputs, i am unable to get any output at all.
There is an output in any case, as i did run it manually as well, and for different inputs with different outputs, i am able to retrieve the output.

Even when i stick and error to the argument - i get the program output.

Could use some insight on this, i am rather new to C#.

Example for output i am unable to retrieve (got this thru manual running of the program):

```
ff: parsing domain file
domain 'KTRIANGLE_TIREWORLD_POMDP' defined
 ... done.
ff: parsing problem file
problem 'KTRIANGLE_TIREWORLD_INST_POMDP__1' defined
 ... done.



Cueing down from goal distance:    3 into depth [1]
                                   2            [1]
                                   1            [1]
                                   0

ff: found legal plan as follows

step    0: MOVE_CAR__LA1A1_LA1A2
        1: MOVE_CAR__LA1A2_LA1A3
        2: CHANGETIRE


time spent:    0.00 seconds instantiating 44 easy, 0 hard action templates
               0.00 seconds reachability analysis, yielding 19 facts and 44 actions
               0.00 seconds creating final representation with 18 relevant facts
               0.00 seconds building connectivity graph
               0.00 seconds searching, evaluating 4 states, to a max depth of 1
               0.00 seconds total time
```

and when i stick a random letter to bug the arguments, i am getting this output, an i am able to retrieve it:

```
usage of ff:

OPTIONS   DESCRIPTIONS

-p <str>    path for operator and fact file
-o <str>    operator file name
-f <str>    fact file name

-i <num>    run-time information level( preset: 1 )
      0     only times
      1     problem name, planning process infos
    101     parsed problem data
    102     cleaned up ADL problem
    103     collected string tables
    104     encoded domain
    105     predicates inertia info
    106     splitted initial state
    107     domain with Wff s normalized
    108     domain with NOT conds translated
    109     splitted domain
    110     cleaned up easy domain
    111     unaries encoded easy domain
    112     effects multiplied easy domain
    113     inertia removed easy domain
    114     easy action templates
    115     cleaned up hard domain representation
    116     mixed hard domain representation
    117     final hard domain representation
    118     reachability analysis results
    119     facts selected as relevant
    120     final domain and problem representations
    121     connectivity graph
    122     fixpoint result on each evaluated state
    123     1P extracted on each evaluated state
    124     H set collected for each evaluated state
    125     False sets of goals <GAM>
    126     detected ordering constraints leq_h <GAM>
    127     the Goal Agenda <GAM>

-d <num>    switch on debugging
```

Comment: Does the program you're starting always write to standard output, or does it sometimes write to standard error instead? That would explain why you don't get anything.

Comment: no, always standard, the only difference i can find between "working" and not working outputs  is the working ones are bit longer, but only ~5 lines longer or so.
And there is always output as well.

Comment: You could try flushing `planWriter` before reading from `m_planStream`

Comment: Thank you! that did the trick! flushed it right before i set the position back to 0.

Comment: I'll add that as an answer then ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flush `planWriter` before reading from `m_planStream`.